# Formula for Total hours between two date times in ms excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to calculate the total hours and minutes between two dates mentioned in excel. i.e.,

> Start date: 02-Sep-2013 02:03:00 AM
>   End Date: 04-Sep-2013 02:04:00 AM

The answer should be **48:01 h:mm**.
Need to consider holidays also, like if 03-Sep-2013 is holiday, then 
The answer should be **24:01 h:mm**.
There are no business hours. It should consider 24 hours. Please help me on this.

Comment: Have a look at `NETWORKDAYS` function

Answer (score 10):

a simple subtraction will get you the value you want: subtract one date/time from the other, and then subtract the number of holiday dates that fall between the two dates.

the trick is to format the result cell as **[h]:mm** (this format works for up to 9999 hours)

Here's an example:
[image]

Comment: Or you could multiply result by 24 like this:  `(B2-B1)*24` to get int value of hours

Answer (score 5):

```
Hours = ((End_Date+End_Time)-(Start_Date+Start_Time))*24
```

For more details please refer the below link

[**Excel**](http://excelsemipro.com/2010/12/calculate-hours-between-two-dates-and-times-in-excel/)

Another Formula with example

```
Cell A1: 2/15/2012  10:00:00 AM

Cell B1: 2/18/2012  08:00:00 PM

What is the elapsed time between both dates (in hours)?

You can get the answer by using the below formula in cell


    C1:= INT(B1-A1)*24+(((B1-A1)-INT(B1-A1))/0.04166666)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with many of the example answers given is definitional.  If you are looking for elapsed time finer than **days** in significant digits the "B2-B1" answer given is incorrect if the end time is earlier in the day than the start time.

Depending on what I am trying to extract I use variations of the following formula to get a more precise "elapsed time".  Depending on why a person lands on this answer the difference in result can make a difference.

```
    =ROUNDDOWN(B3-B2,0) & " Days " 
     & ROUNDDOWN(MOD(B3-B2,1)*24,0) & " hours " 
     & TEXT(MOD(MOD(B3-B2,1)*24,1)*60,"#0") & " Mins"
```

*(formatted for easier reading)*

The image below shows the results of the different answers proposed.  I am not saying the other answers are wrong just that they may not be precise enough depending on the purpose of the answer seeker.
[image]